# Debugging a pattern-matching algorithm

Tags: python, pattern-matching, suffix-tree

The user provides a text file to be searched and a pattern to search for. The program builds a suffix tree and uses it to find all occurrences of the pattern in text, then prints their indexes.

```
class Node:
        def __init__(self, start, substr):
                self.start = start
                self.substr = substr
                self.branches = {}

def insert_into_tree(subroot, suffix, start):
        prefix_len = len(subroot.substr)
        new_suffix = str(suffix[prefix_len:])
        if(len(subroot.branches) == 0):
                left_child = Node(subroot.start, "")
                right_child = Node(start, new_suffix)
                subroot.branches[""] = left_child
                subroot.branches[new_suffix] = right_child
        else:
                for (substr, node) in subroot.branches.items():
                        if len(substr) > 0 and new_suffix.startswith(substr):
                                insert_into_tree(node, new_suffix, start)
                                break
                else:
                        new_child = Node(start, new_suffix)
                        subroot.branches[new_suffix] = new_child

def build_suffix_tree(t_str):
        len_str = len(t_str)
        i = len_str - 1
        root = Node(len_str, "")
        while i >= 0:
                insert_into_tree(root, str(t_str[i:]), i)
                i -= 1
        return root

def find_occurrences(root, pattern):
    for (substr, node) in root.branches.items():
        if pattern in substr:
            print(f"Found at index {node.start}")
        find_occurrences(node, pattern)


file_path = input("Provide path to the text file\n>")
file = open(file_path, "r")
text = file.read()
file.close()

pattern = input("Provide the pattern you're searching for\n>")
root = build_suffix_tree(text)
find_occurrences(root, pattern)
```

My find_occurrences function is supposed to print every index the pattern occurs at. Instead, it prints the position of every index up to and including the last occurrence of the pattern

example:

Provide path to the text file

> lorem.txt

Provide the pattern you're searching for

> sit

Found at index 0

Found at index 19

Found at index 18

Found at index 17

Found at index 16

Found at index 15

Found at index 14

Found at index 13

Found at index 12

Found at index 11

Found at index 10

Found at index 9

Found at index 8

Found at index 7

Found at index 6

Found at index 5

Found at index 4

Found at index 3

Found at index 2

Found at index 1

Answer (score 0):

Check out [pdb - The Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) to debug small programs `python3 -m pdb myscript.py`

- `b` to set a breakpoint (so you can inspect your program there)
- `c` to run up to that point (continue)
- `?` to explore commands .. this will allow you to inspect the live state of your program wherever you breakpoint or continue to